# Maven installation on Windows 7 - 64bit

Tags: java, apache, maven

I have downloaded maven version 'apache-maven-3.3.3' from the apache website. During installation/configuration, while checking the configuration by running 'mvn -version' from the command line, i am getting message, pertaining to java help commands:

```
C:\>mvn --version
Usage: java [-options] class [args...]
           (to execute a class)
   or  java [-options] -jar jarfile [args...]
           (to execute a jar file)
where options include:
    -d32          use a 32-bit data model if available
    -d64          use a 64-bit data model if available
    -server       to select the "server" VM
                  The default VM is server.

    -cp <class search path of directories and zip/jar files>
    -classpath <class search path of directories and zip/jar files>
                  A ; separated list of directories, JAR archives,
                  and ZIP archives to search for class files.
    -D<name>=<value>
                  set a system property
    -verbose:[class|gc|jni]
                  enable verbose output
    -version      print product version and exit
    -version:<value>
                  require the specified version to run
    -showversion  print product version and continue
    -jre-restrict-search | -no-jre-restrict-search
                  include/exclude user private JREs in the version search
    -? -help      print this help message
    -X            print help on non-standard options
    -ea[:<packagename>...|:<classname>]
    -enableassertions[:<packagename>...|:<classname>]
                  enable assertions with specified granularity
    -da[:<packagename>...|:<classname>]
    -disableassertions[:<packagename>...|:<classname>]
                  disable assertions with specified granularity
    -esa | -enablesystemassertions
                  enable system assertions
    -dsa | -disablesystemassertions
                  disable system assertions
    -agentlib:<libname>[=<options>]
                  load native agent library <libname>, e.g. -agentlib:hprof
                  see also, -agentlib:jdwp=help and -agentlib:hprof=help
    -agentpath:<pathname>[=<options>]
                  load native agent library by full pathname
    -javaagent:<jarpath>[=<options>]
                  load Java programming language agent, see java.lang.instrument
    -splash:<imagepath>
                  show splash screen with specified image
    See http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/index.html for more details
```

I am using following environment variables:

```
JAVA_HOME = C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_31
M2_HOME = C:\Maven\apache-maven-3.3.3
M2 = %M2_HOME%\bin
PATH = %JAVA_HOME%\bin;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;c:\TAFC\R12\bin;%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\OpenCL SDK\2.0\bin\x86;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\OpenCL SDK\2.0\bin\x64;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\VSShell\Common7\IDE\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft BizTalk Server 2010\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft BizTalk Server 2010\Bins32;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft BizTalk Server 2010\Bins64;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\ManagementStudio\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\PrivateAssemblies\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft JDBC Driver 4.0 for SQL Server\sqljdbc_4.0\enu\sqljdbc4.jar;D:\ApplicationServer\SBLR14\dbdrivers\sqljdbc_4.0\enu\auth\x64;D:\WASAppServer\bin;D:\WASAppServer\profiles\AppSrv01\TAFJ\appserver\was\jython;C:\Program Files (x86)\Skype\Phone\;%M2%
```

Need help, as to undestand, where i am going wrong.

Comment: Cross check your PATH variables you must have defined something weirdly i.e. copy paste mistake.

Comment: Do you have an evironment variable `MAVEN_OPTS`? If yes, with which value? These maven options are used to [configure the JVM](https://maven.apache.org/configure.html) with which Maven is run. Perhaps there is a syntax error in these options causing the JVM to print the usage text.

Comment: Shouldn't you use `mvn --version`? (i.e. two dashes (--))

Comment: @agold no I can run *mvn -version* just fine. Something must be screwy in the variables that is causing the mvn cmd script to break. Right now I'm suspecting the space in the JAVA_HOME path / JDK installation path. Perhaps quotes need to be added

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose no i am not using MAVEN_OPTS as environment variable

Comment: @BilboBaggins I have checked the PATH variable, but did not find any problem there, do not know how to paste the complete PATH variable here to share with others as well.

Comment: i have added the complete PATH variable, i did not find any problem,let me know if there is any error there

Comment: Open a new console window, type `set` and inspect if PATH, M2_HOME and JAVA_HOME are correctly replaced.

Comment: Can you try `--debug`?